# Authenticity of statement attributed to Abu Bakr: "If I had one foot in paradise, I would still fear Allah's deception"

Tags: hadith, authenticity

Is this narration authentic found in "Successors of the Messenger" by Khalid Muhammad Khalid, p. 70:

"Abu Bakr said if I had one By Allah! I would not feel safe from the deception of Allah, even if I had one foot in paradise."

Answer (score 9):

This narration is not found in any of the authentic collections of *Hadeeth*.

From the answer to [this question on IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/ar/228924):

> ما يذكره بعض الناس عن أبي بكر رضي الله عنه - ويحكيه بعضهم عن عمر رضي الله عنه – أنه قال : " لو كانت إحدى قدمي في الجنة والأخرى خارجها لما أمنت مكر الله " لم نجد له أصلا في كتب أهل الحديث ، ولا نعلم أحدا من أهل العلم ذكره .
>   وقد سئل عنه الشيخ الألباني رحمه الله فقال :
>   " ما أعرفه " انتهى .
>
> As for the saying that is attributed by some people to Abu Bakr, may Allah be pleased with him, and some attribute it to 'Umar, may Allah be pleased with him:
>
> *"If one of my feet were inside Paradise and the other outside it, I would not feel safe from the plan of Allah."*
>
> we could not find any basis for this (narration) in the books of the people of *Hadeeth*, nor did we find any of the scholars make mention of it.
>
> And (when) Shaikh Al-Albaani was asked about it, he said: "I don't know about it."

---

**Side note**

The translation of the word مكر in this context as "deception" is a poor one. I would suggest using the word *plan* or *plot* here in lieu of it.

Comment: Aktually the word "makr" bever means plan and always means deception.                                 Source? I am Lebanese

Comment: The translation "plan" is wrong as مكر الله was translated by classical scholars as the punishment of Allah for the human deceits.